# preg_match help on mutually exclusive conditional matching

Tags: php, preg-match

I've got two options for this plugin.

(1) nofollow all external links in content

and/or

(2) no follow links to this target folder (enter the absolute url to the target folder)

In option 2, the links could be internal OR external.

Both options can be set, neither option may be set, or a single option may be set.

```
if(get_option('my_nofollow') || get_option('my_nofollow_folder')){add_filter('wp_insert_post_data', 'save_my_nofollow' );}
```

So I'm setting a filter when either of these options are set, to the function below. My question is, how do I alter the function so that if (2) is set but not (1) I only add nofollow to links matching the target folder URL?

```
function save_my_nofollow($content) {
$my_folder =  get_option('my_nofollow_folder');
$matches = array();
    preg_match_all('~<a.*>~isU',$content["post_content"],$matches);
    for ( $i = 0; $i <= sizeof($matches[0]); $i++){
        if ( isset($matches[0][$i]) && (preg_match('~' . $my_folder . '~', $matches[0][$i]) 
               || !preg_match( '~'.get_bloginfo('url').'~',$matches[0][$i]))){
        $result = trim($matches[0][$i],">");
        $result .= ' rel="nofollow">';
        $content["post_content"] = str_replace($matches[0][$i], $result, $content["post_content"]);
        }
    }
    return $content;
}
```

UPDATED code with best answer:

```
if(get_option('rseo_nofollow') 
    || get_option('rseo_nofollow_folder')){
    add_filter('wp_insert_post_data', 'save_rseo_nofollow' );
    }

function save_rseo_nofollow($content) {
    $folder =  get_option('rseo_nofollow_folder');
    $externalNoFollow = get_option('rseo_nofollow_external');
    $folderNoFollow = get_option('rseo_nofollow_folder');
    $extRegex = '~'.preg_quote(get_bloginfo('url'), '~') . '~i';
    $intRegex = '~'.preg_quote($folder, '~') . '~i';

    $dom = new DomDocument();
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $dom->loadXml('<root>' . $content['post_content'] . '</root>');

    $links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
    foreach ($links as $link) {
        $href = $link->getAttribute('href');
        if ($href && $externalNoFollow && !preg_match($extRegex, $href)) {
            $link->setAttribute('rel', 'nofollow');
        } elseif ($href && $folderNoFollow && preg_match($intRegex, $href)) {
            $link->setAttribute('rel', 'nofollow');
        }
    }
//  print $dom->saveXml();die;
    //Since we want to strip the root element, we must do so:
    $newContent = '';
    $root = $dom->getElementsByTagName('root')->item(0);
    foreach ($root->childNodes as $child) {
        $newContent .= $dom->saveXml($child);
    }
    $content['post_content'] = $newContent;
return $content;
}
```

Input

```
This is the <a href="http://cnn.com">test</a>. This is the test.
```

Output

```
This is the <a rel="nofollow" href="&quot;http://cnn.com&quot;">test</a>. This is the test.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't parse HTML with regex.  It's not a good idea...  Instead, use the Dom functions.  Note that you may need to wrap the content in an outer root tag (what I added `<root>` here for)(.

```
$externalNoFollow = get_option('my_nofollow_external');
$folderNoFollow = get_option('my_nofollow_folder');
$extRegex = '~'.preg_quote(get_bloginfo('url'), '~') . '~i';
$intRegex = '~'.preg_quote($folder, '~') . '~i';

$dom = new DomDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
if (!$dom->loadHtml('<html><body>' . $content['post_content'] . '</body></html>')) {
    /** Error out, since the loading failed. 
        Make sure `$content['post_content']` is valid html
    **/
    die('Invalid HTML detected');
}

$links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach ($links as $link) {
    $href = $link->getAttribute('href');
    if ($href && $externalNoFollow && !preg_match($extRegex, $href)) {
        $link->setAttribute('rel', 'nofollow');
    } elseif ($href && $folderNoFollow && preg_match($intRegex, $href)) {
        $link->setAttribute('rel', 'nofollow');
    }
}
//Since we want to strip the root element, we must do so:
$newContent = '';
$root = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);
foreach ($root->childNodes as $child) {
    $newContent .= $dom->saveXml($child);
}

$content['post_content'] = $newContent;
return $content;
```

Note, you should add actual error handling incase of invalid HTML...

Comment: @ircmaxell. The only error thrown is: "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" > foreach ($root->childNodes as $child) {

Comment: Works fine for me here...  Could you post the first bit of `$dom->saveXml();`?

Comment: @ircmaxell: Just updated the question with my adaptation of your code. Do you see anything wrong there?

Comment: @ircmaxell: I didn't see where you initialized $folder in your example, so I set it to what I thought you were going for. That could be the problem?

Comment: @Scott: can you post the result of `$dom->saveXML()`?  the only way that *could* happen (invalid argument) is if `<root>` didn't exist at all (which would cause a notice *trying to get property of non-object` at the `$root->childNodes` call).  But I can see in the code it's added, so something funky must be going on...

Comment: When I uncomment the line at the point it appears in my question, print $dom->saveXML() results in empty string

Comment: @ircmaxell: Are you filtering on same?  add_filter('wp_insert_post_data', 'save_rseo_nofollow' );

Comment: @Scott: I think it's because you're passing invalid XML.  I modified it to load as HTML now (which is more forgiving).  Check the edit.  And no, I wasn't using it as a filter, I don't use WP.  I was just testing the native code against a xml/html chunk...

Comment: Works now. But its doubling the quotes in the href and converting them to ascii. I'll post an example in the question.

Comment: @Scott: I'm not sure why.  I've never seen that (especially since you're not modifying the variable).  Do a `var_dump($href);` in the loop to see what it's giving you back out...

Comment: I'll try that. Gotta head out now. Thanks very much for your time with this.